# Azure build fails using ReservedIP

Tags: c#, git, azure, msbuild, continuous-integration

I followed the article [Reserved IP addresses for Cloud Services & Virtual Machines](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/14/reserved-ip-addresses), when I launch the build with the error, using the build process template GitContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12:

The polling operation Create Deployment failed with the error: (500) InternalServerError.

Error Code: InternalError

Message: The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request.

The deployment failed. Check the logs for exceptions that may have caused this failure.

Exception Message: An attempted http request against URI  returned an error: (500) InternalServerError.

Additional Exception Information:

Error Code: InternalError

Message: The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request. (type AzureHttpRequestException)

Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Deployment.Workflow.AzureManagement.v1_7.OperationStatusInfo.EnsureSuccessStatus(Uri requestUri)

   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Deployment.Workflow.Activities.ReportFailedPollResultAndThrow.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)

   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)

   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Answer (score 0):

We experienced the exact same issue. Give it a couple hours and try the deployment again. When we questioned Azure support, here is the root cause analysis they gave us:

> “The product group has completed reviewing this issue and the repeated deployment failures were due to the reserved VIP being requested was marked as in use with old deployment and not freed due to VIP programming issue caused by a platform bug. This has been mitigated after which the VIP programing was completed and it was freed.”